# Upload a file in Selenium and Process it

Tags: c#, selenium, openfiledialog, sendkeys

I'm trying to create a Selenium test that uploads a file into a `OpenFileDialog` window.

I have been usually getting this by the `SendKeys` functionality, but in this particular case this is not enough, as `SendKeys` just puts the path to file and the process I need to be started is launched once "Open" button in `OpenFileDialog` window is pressed.

Have tried also with `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait`, but test by itself cannot find the browser process to type the path to file.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If your button is of type file, then you don't have to click on the button and then do send keys on that button.

Just do send keys on the element whose type is file i.e you don't have to open any **FileDialog**. If it is not of **type file,** then you can't send the path of a file by send keys.

If the element type is not file. You can refer this link:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28064/Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Library

Comment: Sendkeys just put the path to file without launching the OpenFileDialog, but it does not process it.
Usually, after doing the SendKeys, you have to find the button element for clicking on it (Upload, Run, Launch...) to start to process the file you put in the path, as SendKeys does not by itself.
Thats why i'm facing this problem, as the process starts when pressing "open" in the FileDialog, and FileDialog is not handled by Selenium.

Comment: If the element is of type file, then it is not necessary to find any element for processing this file. Can you give me your URL so that I can check or please share the HTML of the element? Is there any submit button on the UI?

Comment: Hi, I finally got this working by setting visible property of the FileDialog file type to visible, as if it's not available, sendKeys method can't work.
Thank you.